# Definitive integral from derivative

Tags: derivatives, definite-integrals

I have a simple differential equation:

$$\frac{\partial p(x,y)}{\partial y} = -g$$

$y$ is defined from $-1$ to $\zeta$, and I also have a boundary condition, which is:

$$y=\zeta:p=sinh(x)$$

I am 100% sure that the problem is stated correctly, but it looks to me that these two conditions:

- $y=\zeta:p=sinh(x)$
- $y$ is defined from $-1$ to $\zeta$

contradict each other, because using the first condition I am getting: $p=-gy + F(x)$ and $F(x)=sinh(x)+g \zeta$, so the full solution would be $p(x,y)=-gy+sinh(x)+g\zeta$.
But by taking the definite integral from $-1$ to $\zeta$ I am getting $\int_{-1}^{\zeta} \frac{\partial p(x,y)}{\partial y} dy = p(x,y)=-g(\zeta+1)$

So, can someone tell me where is my mistake?

Comment: your forgetting to plug in your values for the definite integral. 
$p(x,\zeta) - p(x,-1)$
using boundry conditions
$\sinh(x) - p(x,-1) = -g\zeta-g$
$\sinh(x)  + g\zeta + g = p(x,-1)$
using the formula you derived before, when you plug in -1 you get the same

Comment: I've put a clearer solution down below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a definite integral you need to remember to substitute your values in and subtract them
$$\int_{-1}^{\zeta} \frac{\partial p(x,y)}{\partial y} dy = p(x,\zeta)-p(x,-1)$$
Using the boundry conditions you stated we can replace $p(x,\zeta)$ with $\sinh x$ doing so gives us
$$\int_{-1}^{\zeta} \frac{\partial p(x,y)}{\partial y} dy = \sinh(x)-p(x,-1)$$
However using the differential equation you wrote above it becomes
$$\int_{-1}^{\zeta} -g \, dy = \sinh(x)-p(x,-1)$$
Doing the integration gives
$$-g\zeta - g  = \sinh(x)-p(x,-1)$$
which is equivilent to $-g(\zeta + 1)$. We can now solve for $p(x,-1)$
$$-g\zeta - g + p(x,-1) = \sinh(x)$$
move over the $-g\zeta - g$
$$ p(x,-1) = \sinh(x) + g\zeta + g$$
Using the formula you $p(x,y)$ that you derived, you can see when you substitute $y = -1$ you get the same result. So it is consistent :)

Comment: Thank you very much! 
Is it correct to say that either way, by finding the indefinite integral we get a more general solution whereas by simple integration of the definite integral we restrict ourselves to know the value only In two points and the solution is less general?

Comment: @John Yes that's completely correct if you want to not restrict yourself using the integral integrate from y to $\zeta$, and you get the same result but using a different integration measure. For example
$$\int_{y}^{\zeta} \frac{\partial p(x,\gamma)}{\partial \gamma} d \gamma $$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @John No problem :)